# How to create a file on UESTUDIO FTP window when the folder it's empty?

Tags: windows-7, laptop

When I'm editing some files ( html, css, js ) on UESTUDIO by FTP I'm able to browser folders, create new files on existing folders, but when I create a new folder and try to create a new file it won't allow me to select the "create new file" choice on the menu.

Also, if I uncheck the "Show current directory only" option, then the menu to create folders and files on the current one ( that worked before ) disapears and I'm unable to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need first to synchronize your local copy and the remote one if it exist? (as mentioned here: http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/sync_local_to_remote.html)

Comment: I usually do that on the desktop, but on this case it's for when I'm working on my laptop remotely and I want just to modify the files on the server without a local copy. ( thanks for the answer though ).